# Webstorm run command when editor starts

Tags: webstorm, grunt-contrib-watch

Is there a way to have Webstorm run a cmd code when it stars. I'm using grunt watch and at the moment I have to go to the terminal and type "grunt watch" to start the task but I'm pretty sure I'll forget this from time to time and I want it automated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to have Webstorm run a cmd code when it stars.

No.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11818 -- star/vote/comment to get notified on progress.

Comment: This feature was implemented in the meantime. You can find it under Settings | Tools | Startup Tasks